# the reason that ,why , is because

Tags: grammar

I have bumped into  just A LOT  of English native speakers saying:
  " the reason  I need to buy a flight ticket right now is because I have to get back to the office tomorrow morning" ( a tourist at a travel agency)

"The reason I want to go to  Peru is because you can eat one of the best CEVICHES ever"  (ceviche is raw fish cut into small pieces and flavored with lemon ).

I have so frecuently heard "the reason I...is because I ..."  that I have always assumed it is the right way to say. But to my great surprise , a beautiful Irish woman told me that saying" The reason  I ... is because I... " is  redundant.

According to her  " the reason I bought this T-shirt is I need to play football tomorrow" 
Or " the reason I am here is I wanted to see you" are correct sentences.

As she is Irish, I guess it must be true. I'm wondering whether it's just about formal and informal ways of saying the same thing,or it's a real mistake.

Can someone make this clear to me?

Comment: Spot on. Both the reason is because and the reason why are saying *the reason behind the reason is.* So, A is the reason for B. The reason for B is A.  Not A is the reason why B. Not the reason for B is because of A.

Comment: Not in total agreement with the lady in the story. We can remove "because" in those sentences but it's not redundant. The word "is" is only a linking verb. You can't *"ising"* something. It just connects a subject to it's verb. It's a special type of verb (a copula). We can remove "because" as it has become implied in spoken or written English (i.e., *the reason for me stealing is I need money* -- because is implied but "is" does not replace the purpose of "because"). They don't mean the same. The OP's story was saying they do. I don't agree. Cleaner, yes. They don't mean the same though.

Comment: I disagree. EITHER "The _reason_ I'm hurrying is _that_ I have a train to catch" OR "I'm hurrying _because_ I have a train to catch".

Answer (score -1):

It would be cleaner English to say "I need to buy a flight ticket right now because I have to get back to the office tomorrow morning" This is known as the art of precis and generally features in advanced English classes.  The original is not wrong, just a bit messy.